Liquefaction of gases in the absence of gravity
Would we be able to liquefy gases in the absence of gravity?
I personally feel that small drops of liquid would form on applying enough pressure, and the drops would float about in the gas like an aerosol, because the liquid molecules don't have a direction to settle down.
But I also have a feel that maybe the gas would behave like a supercritical fluid, even below the critical temperature...
So what happens actually?

Gravity does not play direct role in ability of gases to liquify. For nano/microdroplets on condensation seeds within free gas, gravity is negligible force, compared to dynamics of interaction with air molecules. And it plays even less role in condensation on bulk surfaces. // Review the guide How to ask and Asking FAQs to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

Perhaps you should modify the question to "are liquids possible in the absence of gravity". Whether liquifying is possible (by us?) seems beside the point. // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jJ081ZH6eAA

We would indeed expect small droplets, if they can be nucleated or if we sufficiently supercool the material to force a spinodal process.
In a sense, condensation in the absence of gravity is commonplace in our experience. Technically, Earth's gravity still exists in our atmosphete, but it is a minor player in the fluid dynamics and nucleation processes when water vapor condenses there. Nucleation may be provided by uplifted dust or salt particles, bacteria, or even acid molecules formed from stroms/pollution that "attract" water molecules. So we get the condensate in the form of fine, dispersed particles, meaning clouds/fog. We would expect a similar outcome in actual zero-gravity conditions.

Gravity is a minor player until you get soaked in a rainshower.

Which is after the condensation process is done, with a little coalescence of the condensate particles on the side. Get thee an umbrella!

What constrains any material are the intramolecular forces and a partial pressure greater than the equilibrium vapor pressure. A special case is a temperature low enough that molecules do not have enough energy to evaporate; in this case the material will not evaporate, many common solids, ice in comets, etc. fit in this category.
The atmosphere on Earth, held to the planet by gravity, is a container for gases. A low density air mass containing water vapor is forced upwards by the effect of gravity on more dense surrounding air; as the air rise it expands, adiabatically cooling. When the partial pressure exceeds the equilibrium vapor pressure, vapor condenses. This is possible only if the surrounding atmosphere can contain the moist air mass. The atmosphere is maintained by gravity.
A common example: an open pot boils dry quickly, covered pot more slowly, a sealed impervious container can hold a liquid for eons. The atmosphere, held in place by gravity, is a more subtle container.
